# Open text file and write to it android

Tags: java, android, text

My app is structured by an edit text and a button that sends the words to a file (script) located into /system/etc/init.d and if the file is not there it creates a new one.
When I rewrite something in the edit text I wanna append the text in same file and not recreate a new one.
Hope you can give me some example code and help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sth like this.

`FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("script", MODE_APPEND);`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.

```
    File externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(externalStorageDir , "myfile.txt");

    if(myFile.exists())
    {
       try
       {
  FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
           OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
           myOutWriter.append("test");
           myOutWriter.close();
           fOut.close();
        } catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        myFile.createNewFile();
    }
```

just set permission like this

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't create a new file and neither write to it